# Error: Can't resolve all parameters for InMemoryStorageStrategy: (?)

Tags: javascript, angular

After updating the version from 8 to 9, I was facing this error after compiling the application.

I had wasted whole day to find the solution.

Error: Can't resolve all parameters for InMemoryStorageStrategy: (?)

Comment: Please include the code.

Answer (score 1):

The error may come from using a version of `ngx-webstorage` @4.0.1 or lower.
If this is the case, run `npm install ngx-wegstorage@4.0.2`

Answer (score 0):

Without any code examples this is really hard to answer. You might be missing the `@Injectable()` decorator on that service.

Comment: I don't know in which component its throwing an error. After compiling the application, it simply throws this error.

Comment: Error: Can't resolve all parameters for InMemoryStorageStrategy: (?).
    at getUndecoratedInjectableFactory (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:12269)
    at injectableDefOrInjectorDefFactory (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:12259)
    at providerToFactory (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:12324)
    at providerToRecord (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:12289)
    at R3Injector.processProvider (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:12186)

Comment: Also,  I had verified all the service class @Injectable() decorator is present. Also, Do we need to add @Injectable() in a model class ?

Comment: `InMemoryStorageStrategy` would be a service in your code, i suppose? as i said, it's very hard to answer without code examples...

Comment: No, there is no service called InMemoryStorageStrategy in my code. I can understand that you need code example. But in error its not saying any particular class. It's just simply throwing this error Error: Can't resolve all parameters for InMemoryStorageStrategy.

Comment: Do we have any configurations to suppress this error? I can't find a solution for past two days.

Comment: if it's not in your code then i guess you will need to update whatever library is providing `InMemoryStorageStrategy`. And no, it's not possible to suppress, because it does not compile.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and the only thing that worked for me was uninstalling `node_modules` and running `npm install` again.